# Something like "turning lemons into lemonade"

Tags: idioms

Is there a Chinese saying roughly equivalent in meaning to "turning lemons into lemonade"?

From Wikipedia,

> "When life gives you lemons, make lemonade" is a proverbial phrase
>   used to encourage optimism and a can-do attitude in the face of
>   adversity or misfortune. "Lemons" in this expression is used in the
>   informal sense of the word, to indicate an unfortunate or inadequate
>   situation, a meaning which probably stems from the sour and acidic
>   taste of unsweetened lemon. "Lemonade" on the other hand, is a
>   sweetened form of this same acerbic fruit, and so in the context of
>   this expression, conveys the potential for pleasure and opportunity in
>   seemingly bad situations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some phrases of close meanings:

- 化干戈为玉帛   turn hostility into peace;
- 转危为安 / 化险为夷       turn danger into safety;
- 化压力为动力   turn the pressure of life into power;
- 转悲为喜 turn sorrow into joy;
- 化悲痛为力量   turn sadness into power;
- 变废为宝    turn rubbish into useful things;
- 化失败为教训  turn failure into lessons

Comment: Nice list. I just want to add 化腐朽为神奇, similar to 变废为宝.